# How can I downgrade Node using NPM?

Tags: node.js, installation, downgrade

I need to downgrade my Node version from 10.x to 8.12. It appears I should be able to run this command:

> $ npm install node@8.12

That runs, says `removed 1 package, updates 1 package...`

But then I check version and it keeps returning my old version:

> $ node -v
>
> v10.11.0

Am I doing something wrong or misunderstanding the commands/process?

Answer (score 15):

I am sheepishly answering my own question.

The issue was that node was a global install. Therefore, I needed to install the lower version globally ala the `-g` option:

> $ npm install -g node@8.12